# Drupal Menu-How to get Hierarchy

Tags: php, drupal, breadcrumbs

In Drupal how can I get selected menu items hierarchy?

If I selected item3, how can I get the the entire hierarchy...(eg:item1->item2-item3)

If I use `$menu_item = menu_get_item();`, I will get active menu item name (eg: item3). But I want to get it like (item1->item2->item3).

Answer (score 1):

```
$parent = menu_get_item($vars['mid']);
$vars['parent'] = $parent['pid'];

$hasParent = menu_get_menu();
$hasParent = $hasParent['items'][$parent]['pid'];
```

this code will give you the parent menus information and you can print that.

Comment: how u getting this??...$vars['mid']

Comment: $var['mid'] is the variable. In your case you can pass that variable which has the value of last menu.